# Break / Quit / Exit in SAS

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am using SAS Enterprise Guide and am running a program that runs for a long time (about 30 min).

I want to be able to do the following:

1. Exit my program at a defined point.
2. Examine the contents of the Log at this point.

Is there a command that allows me to do the above? I am basically looking for something like a break/exit/quit statement that maintains the SAS Log.

Comment: Try using `endsas;`.

Comment: Just had to deal with this regarding ENDSAS; - in its own form it cannot be combined with conditions (if/then). This explains a way to get around it http://www.sascommunity.org/sugi/SUGI95/Sugi-95-73%20Tilanus.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Enterprise Guide way of doing this is to break your program into multiple smaller program files.  Then you run each of those, either individually if you want to be able to see the details before moving on, or in a linked flow if you want to just run them whole thing and see outputs but not stop it (though you could always stop it using the stop button if something came up).

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Why would you want to end SAS (meaning, entirely kill the SAS.EXE process)?  You wouldn't be able to see your intermediate datasets or pick up where you left off.  Enterprise Guide has a whole suite of conditionals and such created just to make this sort of thing possible - use them.